# How to pass an array of objects to a function in julia?

Tags: julia

I want to pass an array of objects to a function and return another array of the same size. How should I do this ? The code should be so fast. For example consider the below code:

```
struct triangle
    height::Float64
    base::Float64
end

function area(height::Float64, base::Float64)
    return 0.5*base*height
end
```

I want to define a function which returns the area of an array of triangles. 
What is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

You can leverage Julia's broadcasting syntax for this. Consider:

```
struct Triangle # Note: Julia convention is to capitalize types
    height::Float64
    base::Float64
end

# Define an area method for the Triangle type
area(t::Triangle) = 0.5 * t.height * t.base

# Create an area of random triangles
triangle_array = [Triangle(rand(), rand()) for _ in 1:10]

# Now we can use dot syntax to broadcast our area function over the array of triangles
area.(triangle_array)
```

Note that this differs from your code in that it directly uses the `Triangle` object for dispatch in the call to the `area` function. The `area` function then doesn't take `height` and `base` arguments but just a single `Triangle` object and accesses its `height` and `base` fields (`t.height` and `t.base`).

Comment: In general it is better to divide by `2` (an `Int`) instead of multiplying with `0.5` (a `Float64`). Consider the case where `height` and `base` would be e.g. `Float32`s, then the former would result in a `Float32`, whereas the latter would unnecessarily promote to `Float64`. I would thus write `area(t::Triangle) = t.height * t.base / 2`.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some benchmarks for computing this with:

- map: `map(area, triangles)`
- comprehension: `[area(triangle) for triangle in triangles]
- broadcasting: `area.(triangles)`

using interpolation `$` on the non-local global variable `triangles` (based on @DNF comment).

## Definitions

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("BenchmarkTools")
using BenchmarkTools


struct Triangle
    height::Float64
    base::Float64
end


function area(t::Triangle)
    0.5 * t.height * t.base
end


triangles = [Triangle(rand(), rand()) for _ in 1:1000000]
```

## Results

```
julia> @benchmark map(area, $triangles)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB
  allocs estimate:  3
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.168 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.510 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.485 ms (10.00% GC)
  maximum time:     43.540 ms (91.62% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2008
  evals/sample:     1
```

```
julia> @benchmark [area(triangle) for triangle in $triangles]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB
  allocs estimate:  3
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.150 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.921 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.327 ms (10.76% GC)
  maximum time:     45.883 ms (91.42% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2144
  evals/sample:     1
```

```
julia> @benchmark area.($triangles)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.165 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.224 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.961 ms (10.13% GC)
  maximum time:     44.156 ms (89.33% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2544
  evals/sample:     1
```

This would indicate that for this input size, the broadcasting method seems to be the fastest.

For different input size, relative timings may be different, so it is probably a good idea to benchmark it yourself for your use case

Comment: When benchmarking with BenchmarkTools.jl, always remember to interpolate global non-const variables. If I replace `triangles` with `$triangles` above, I get similar runtimes for all three, in which case I prefer broadcasting due to the syntax.